# Partial application of MASS::rlm(method="MM")

Tags: r, ggplot2, pryr

I'm looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487418/mm-robust-estimation-in-ggplot2-using-stat-smooth-with-method-rlm) in which someone is attempting to use `MASS::rlm(method="MM")` from within `geom_smooth()` in ggplot.

I thought this would be a grand opportunity for `pryr::partial`, but have been confused by what I think is a dispatch issue.

First an example of what I think *should* work:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(pryr)

dat <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=jitter(1:10))

rlm.mm <- partial(rlm, method="MM")

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_smooth(method="rlm.mm")
```

Alas, I get the following error when attempting to plot:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  the ... list does not contain 3 elements
```

My thinking is that this has to do with the ordering of parameters, with the named parameter usurping one of the positional arguments.

So, the question here is, is there a way to do partial application of this function where it is an optional, named argument that is supplied?